# Cannot create instance of Service Reference

Tags: c#, web-services, visual-studio, windows-phone

I have added a Service Reference to my Windows Phone 8 Project and it is showing in the Service Reference folder.

When I try to create an instance of the service, such as:

```
var service = new MobileService();
```

It doesn't recognise what `MobileService` is. Same goes for when I try doing `using MobileService;` at the top of the class.

Where am I going horribly wrong?

Comment: with your cursor under "MobileService" presse CRTL+. does it show any context menu to import a namespace?

Comment: Off topic, but just so you can increase code quality. Using var can be very unclear to read. Explicit declaring is much more clear.

Comment: My managing director reprimands me whenever I don't use var. I too do not like using var but... meh.

Comment: I like using var when it is clear its type just like your examplebecause you're instantiating a MobileService right there. if it were from a method call then i'd use explicit typing.

Comment: See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/. Also, is this a web site "project" in which you're trying to use the service reference?

Comment: It's a Windows Phone 8 application

Answer (score 1):

The class is probably called MobileServiceClient. Click the show all files option for your project and you can view the generated code of the service references.

Comment: Try that. I don't see any MobileServiceClient. I do however see MobileService.xsd, MobileService1.xsd, MobileService2.xsd, MobileService3.xsd .... I think that's because i've been deleting and re-adding the mobile service in. But this shouldn't mess it up...

Comment: There must be a .cs file. The class names are over there